# Power BI - How to shift dates (years) based on a filter

Tags: dynamic, parameters, powerbi

I have a table with a date column and I would like the user to be able to select fiscal year's start month. Based on the user filter selection, the table (which includes the dates) would assign the appropriate fiscal years.

For example, I have a table with dates, but the column 'fy' isn't dynamic. It remains fixed at the default parameter value.

[image: Table of dates and counts]

If the user filtered on "1" (January), then that would indicate a normal calendar year and all the rows in the above example would belong to year = 2021. If the user selected "3" (March), indicating they wanted the fiscal year to begin March 1, then the first two rows in the above example should be assigned year = 2020 and all other rows would be year = 2021.

See below. As it is, the data plots like the upper-right chart. When the slicer is at 3, I want the chart to look like the lower-left chart. How can I make a dynamic chart that does this?

[image: Example charts]

Maybe creating a new table that re-queries every time the parameter is changed? But I'm not sure how to do that.